# Boostrap: .affix-bottom doesn't move to the bottom of its parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's affix side-navigation. When you scroll down to the bottom of the element which the navigation refers to, the class .affix-bottom is applied to the navigation element and it should scroll (exactly in the way the side navigation in the [Boostrap documentary](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html) works).

However, when the class changes to affix-bottom and the following styles are applied, the affix-navigation moves to the top of the page (and out of the viewport).

```
affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 200px;
}
```

I am not sure wether the issue is related to Bootstrap. I have compared the styles Bootstrap natively uses and the styles I use and they are exactly the same.

This is the html I use:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar" id="navfaq">
      <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix-top">
        <li class="">
          <a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor1'); return false;" href="#anchor1">Go to anchor1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor2'); return false;" href="#anchor2">Go to anchor2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor3'); return false;" href="#anchor3">Go to anchor3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor4'); return false;" href="#anchor4">Go to anchor4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor5'); return false;" href="#anchor5">Go to anchor5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor6'); return false;" href="#anchor6">Go to anchor6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <button class="btn pull-center">Contact</button>
            <button class="btn pull-center">Call</button>
            <p class="caption">on weekdays</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
<div class="span9">
  ...
</div>
```

As Bootstrap's Affix is having some issues, I wrote my own script which changes the classes of the affix from .affix-top to .affix when you scroll further than the top-position of the .row element and when you scroll to the bottom of the .row element, it will add the class .affix-bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').height() >= (($('#anchor1').offset().top + $('.row .span9').height() - $('.navbar').height() - $(window).scrollTop() - 40 ) ) ) {
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix');
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix-bottom');
    }
    else {
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix');
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix-bottom');      
      if( $(window).scrollTop() >= (($('#anchor1').offset().top) - ($('.navbar').height()) - 20)) {
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix-top');
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix');
      }
      else if( $(window).scrollTop() < (($('#anchor1').offset().top) - ($('.navbar').height()) - 20)) {
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix-top');
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This keept my up all night and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Ok, I finally fixed it. However, it's more of a workaround. I changed the JS to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').height() >= (($('#allgemeine-fragen-zu-meinunterricht-de').offset().top + $('.row .span9').height() - $('.navbar').height() - $(window).scrollTop() - 40 ) ) ) {
      $(".span3.bs-docs-sidebar").css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'height': $('.row .span9').height()
      });
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix');
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix-bottom');
    }
    else {
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix');
      $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix-bottom');      
      if( $(window).scrollTop() >= (($('#allgemeine-fragen-zu-meinunterricht-de').offset().top) - ($('.navbar').height()) - 20)) {
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix-top');
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix');
      }
      else if( $(window).scrollTop() < (($('#allgemeine-fragen-zu-meinunterricht-de').offset().top) - ($('.navbar').height()) - 20)) {
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').addClass('affix-top');
        $('.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav').removeClass('affix');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I have no idea why it's working in Bootstrap without the position:relativ and the equivalent height for the span3.

Comment: The Stackoverflow way to "solve" a question is to post an answer and accept it; you can do this yourself for your own questions too. Please don't "tag" it as "[solved]".

Answer (score 0):

try this

just add class **affix** to div

```
<div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar affix affix-top" id="navfaq">
            <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav ">
                <li class=""><a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor1'); return false;" href="#anchor1">Go
                    to anchor1</a> </li>
                <li class=""><a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor2'); return false;" href="#anchor2">Go
                    to anchor2</a> </li>
                <li class=""><a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor3'); return false;" href="#anchor3">Go
                    to anchor3</a> </li>
                <li class=""><a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor4'); return false;" href="#anchor4">Go
                    to anchor4</a> </li>
                <li class=""><a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor5'); return false;" href="#anchor5">Go
                    to anchor5</a> </li>
                <li class="active"><a onclick="scrollToAnchor('anchor6'); return false;" href="#anchor6">
                    Go to anchor6</a> </li>
                <li><a>
                    <button class="btn pull-center">
                        Contact</button>
                    <button class="btn pull-center">
                        Call</button>
                    <p class="caption">
                        on weekdays</p>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```